# Run AWS Lambda function for a certain period

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

How can I run AWS Lambda function for a certain period? Basically I want to invoke my Lambda once, and run it as long as the Lambda function receives particular JSON-response from another API. In other words, it would poll a service, like for example every 5 minutes or so, and stop when it gets the information needed.

AWS rule is not an option because I want the function to be run only when invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern is not a great one for AWS Lambda, as it has a time limit for execution of 300s.  In addition, you are charged by the second of execution, so even if your lambda is running waiting to poll another resource, you will be paying for idle time.

You mention not wanting to use an AWS Events Rule, however what about the following approach:

1. When the lambda function is invoked, check if an associated AWS Rule is defined.  If not, create an AWS Events Rule using the API. If it is defined, move ahead.
2. Carry out the poll of the other API, and look for the special result.
3. If not found, exit the lambda, confident that the AWS rule will invoke it again for the next poll.
4. If found, then use the AWS Events Rule API to delete the AWS rule, and then exit.

This way, the lambda will itself manage the lifetime of the rule - creating it when it wants to start polling on a cycle, and deleting it when it no longer needs it.